# I'm not a fat hen

Tags: wordplay, letters, quote

Start with the phrase
  `I'm not a fat hen.`
and perform the following steps in some order to find **a famous quotation**:

- **Add a letter.**
- **Remove a letter.**
- **Add a word.**
- **Remove a word.**
- **Join two words.**
- **Split a word.**
- **Change a letter.**
- **Rearrange words.**

*Note: You can ignore punctuation, and add/remove punctuation as required, at any point.

Thus, `I'm` is one word.*

Comment: I like these puzzles, but try not to repeat quotations :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change a letter:

> I'm not a fat her.

Join two words:

> I'm not a father.

Add a word:

> I'm not a your father.

Remove a word:

> I'm not your father.

Remove a letter:

> I'm no your father.

Add a letter:

> Iam no your father.

Split a word:

> I am no your father.

Rearrange words:

> **No, I am your father.** (Often misquoted as "Luke...".)

Comment: That's not true.  That's impossible!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping on the superhero theme...

> I'm not a fat hen

Change a letter-

> I'm not a fat her.

Add a letter

> I'm not a fat hero.

Add a word

> I'm not a fat hero Thinemansays

Rearrange words

> Thinemansays I'm not a fat hero

Split a word

> Thineman says I'm not a fat hero.

Join two words

> Thineman saysI'm not a fat hero.

Remove a word

> Thineman-not a fat hero.

Remove a letter

> Thinman-not a fat hero.